# Exception "The SPListItem being updated was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields." at changing TaxonomyField value

Tags: 2010, taxonomy

This problem appears only on one particular Document Library. I use

```
TaxonomyField.SetFieldValue(myItem, myTaxonomyFieldValue);
```

and it works fine everywhere except this lib. Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

IF everything has been setup properly:

- Added an extra note field to the schema.xml for each Taxonomy field
- Changed the throttling settings

AND everything stated in this article is clear and okey-dokey:

http://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/fix-the-splistitem-being-updated-was-not-retrieved-with-all-taxonomy-fields/

then I would suggest to check this:

- open site collection content type using SharePoint Web Interface:
- site settings
- site content types
- open the content type
- In the Columns list open the column giving the error
- Modify site column
- Edit the term set column setting
- save

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing exactly the same issue, except I am getting these errors when trying to set values through the browser too.

Comment: I've solved this issue in a quite awkward manner. Just created a new DocLib and moved all content in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue while updating one of the taxonomy field programmatically (server API) of a document library.

There was a CAML query to retrieve only specific items I needed to update and brought in only taxonomy field not the corresponding taxonomy "note" field (generally ends with taxonomyFieldName_0).

This below line was culprit in my case, after commenting the line the error was gone.

```
spQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name="TaxonomyFieldName" />" //commented this line
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when trying to update/add an item to a list in SharePoint 2013, both from the UI or through the API, which was using a custom list template. This was specifically occuring for a taxonomy column.

I created a generic list (through the UI) and added the same columns as the ones in the list template, and compared the two lists together via SharePoint Manager. What was missing in the list template was the "Taxonomy Catch All Column" (like below). Once I added it to the list template, the error disappeared.

```
<Field Type="LookupMulti" DisplayName="Taxonomy Catch All Column" StaticName="TaxCatchAll" Name="TaxCatchAll" ID="{GUID}" ShowInViewForms="FALSE" List="{List-GUID}" WebId="Web-GUID" Required="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" ShowField="CatchAllData" SourceID="{Source-GUID}" Mult="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" AllowDeletion="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" Version="2" />
```

This [article](http://www.andrewconnell.com/sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-in-depth-look-into-the-taxonomy-parts) explains the use and need of this column.